# Curl_open memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, libcurl

In my application , I am seeing these leaks in valgrind in curl. My app initializes 4 curl handles during launch and uses them for download data and then resets the handle using curl_easy_reset. The handles will be cleaned up on App exit ,by curl_easy_cleanup.

I think this flow is correct and there should not be any leaks ,but valgrind shows the below leaks

==3238== 229,504 (77,056 direct, 152,448 indirect) bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7,503 of 7,506
==3238==    at 0x48411F8: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:752)
==3238==    by 0x52AA09B: Curl_open (in /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.5.0)

==3238== 74,974 (352 direct, 74,622 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7,480 of 7,506
==3238==    at 0x4841478: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
==3238==    by 0x5A68ABF: ares_init_options (in /usr/lib/libcares.so.2.3.0)

Curl_open is called from curl_easy_init( 4 calls) and extra curl_easy_init(invoked by curl_easy_perform) but curl_easy_cleanup is called only 4 times . Does the extra curl_easy_init calls from curl_easy_perform has anything to do with the leaks? Below is the psudo code

```
void    init()
{
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        curlHandles[i].curlhandle = curl_easy_init();
        curlHandles[i].isInUse    = FALSE;
    }

}
void deinit()
{
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        curlHandles[i].curlhandle = curl_easy_cleanup();
        curlHandles[i].isInUse    = FALSE;
    }
}

void download()
{
   lock()
   curl_handle = get_free_handle()
   unlock()
 
   /* set curl opts */
   curl_easy_setopt();

   /* perform download */
   curl_easy_perform();

   /* reset */
   curl_easy_reset(curl_handle);
}
```

Comment: That would imply curl has a bug and you should report it to the curl project instead. I do consider it unlikely though, but since you haven't shown any code we can't help you more.

Comment: @DanielStenberg , I have added the psudo code of what my app is doing. I am seeing the leaks when I use url with DNS name and the leaks are less with ip based urls.